# Stop emacs warning at startup

Tags: linux, emacs, systemd

For some reason emacs started to display a warning at whenever my computer starts up. The warning looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPrgi.jpg. The text-form of the error is:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading '/home/username/.emacs':
>
> error: No such directory found via CDPATH environment variable
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the cause of the error in your initialization file. Start Emacs with the '--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

It seems, from the error, emacs is having trouble finding the ~/.emacs config file.

**This warning is incorrect**, however, since after this emacs normally works fine for me without any error, after this error message at start-up. It is however a mild inconvenience.

If I had to guess why it's happening I would say it might be somehow related to the way my fstab has been set up. It's slightly different from the norm but nothing too unusual. The setup is like this (in human language):

- / is mounted on a normal partition.
- /home is mounted on a LUK encrypted partition. (One thing to note is that I have always had my /home encrypted but emacs only started to play up recently)
- I also have two external drives that are auto-mounted to run my media server via my workstation (although I don't think this is related to the issue at hand)

Is there anyway that I can prevent emacs from displaying this in the future? I don't have emacs in my System 'Autostart' so I'm not sure why it keeps popping up at every boot.

**UPDATE**

I decided to look into the log from my last reboot:

```
$ journalctl -b | grep emacs
```

..and saw this:

```
Jul 21 14:30:46 my-PC-name systemd[3000]: Started apps-emacs-6284d6112ffa4ee29646bcb4b3b00b0f.scope.
Jul 21 14:30:54 my-PC-name systemd[3000]: apps-emacs-6284d6112ffa4ee29646bcb4b3b00b0f.scope: Succeeded.
```

Why would emacs starts itself when it's disabled as per below?

```
systemctl --user status emacs
```

```
● emacs.service - Emacs text editor
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service; disabled; vendor preset>
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: info:emacs
             man:emacs(1)
             https://gnu.org/software/emacs/
```

My emacs.service file doesn't look different from the default:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: What's the error backtrace when you start Emacs with the `--debug-init` option?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh There is no error backtrace when I start Emacs with --debug-init.

Comment: @Mishka Are you saying that with `--debug-init` you **do** still see the "error: No such directory found via CDPATH environment variable" message (also telling you to use `--debug-init`), but the debugger is not invoked?

Comment: @phils No, with `--debug-init` there is no error. As mentioned in the post, the error only appears after startup. After that there is no issue at all.

Comment: Well that's evidentially not so -- the quoted message tells you that the error occurred *while* loading your init file.  That error is generated *only* during startup.

Comment: If you mean that this error only happens the first time that Emacs is run after booting your PC, then of course you would need to be using `--debug-init` for that first run.

Comment: @phils

emacs only displays this when I start up my machine, when it **automatically** starts. 

Any run after that, it is fine. I use emacs regularly for my blog and workflow so would notice any issue (especially with the init file) if it comes up.

My question is: Why is emacs starting after my PC is booted? I have not got emacs on my Autostart list.

Comment: Now that you seem to have established what is causing Emacs to start automatically, you can undoubtedly change the command to include `--debug-init`

Comment: @phils
"Now that you seem to have established what is causing Emacs to start automatically.." -- No I certainly have **not** establish that and that is exactly what i'm trying to solve. This brings me back to the point I have repeated several times:.. *"I don't have emacs in my System 'Autostart' so I'm not sure why it keeps popping up at every boot."* ......  *"My question is: Why is emacs starting after my PC is booted? I have not got emacs on my Autostart list."*

Comment: Is it not `systemd` starting it?  All the edits are about systemd.  You even seem to have a log message confirming it.  I assume you created the systemd config yourself, so if you don't want it, then maybe just remove that config?  In any case, I'm only trying to help with the *Emacs* problem -- I know nothing at all about systemd -- so if you don't *actually* care about the `emacs` error then perhaps remove that tag.  If you *do* care about it, then my suggestion is unchanged -- set the debug option in the command which is running Emacs, which is something that you *appear* to have located.

Comment: 1) It sounds like you don't even want Emacs to start at boot?  If so, make sure it's disabled in both the system and user instances of systemd (sounds like it's already disabled for your user, and I can't see why anyone would ever want a system Emacs daemon). Note that whatever the "Autostart" you mention is, it might not be related to systemd, but for sure the unit files you posted are for systemd.

Comment: 2) If you do want Emacs to start from systemd, enable it for your user, and make sure that it doesn't start before something it depends on (e.g. mounting and decrypting your $HOME).  You can do this with `Requires` (dependency) and `After` (ordering) in the unit file.  You can test without rebooting like so: `systemctl --user daemon-reload ; systemctl --user restart emacs`.

Comment: @jpkotta I think it's definitely systemd that's starting my emacs, probably even before /home is mounted, looking at the journalctl log above.

I will look into this today and try one of the two solutions:
1) Disable emacs autostart from systemd system instance. It's tricky because I don't know how it's "enabled" right now.
2) Overwrite emacs to start in systemd user instance but config it to do so after /home is mounted...

Comment: "It seems, from the error, emacs is having trouble finding the ~/.emacs config file." - To me it looks like Emacs is finding and loading your `~/.emacs` file, but something in this file is causing an error. Some searching suggests that the only place this error message can come from is the Lisp function `cd`. Are you using it in your configuration, or is your configuration calling something that is using it?